# BufferReader going still running while connection is closed

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I have a somewhat simple server meaning that i am trying to learn different design patterns by making a server as object orientated as possible. Suprisingly so far i havnt had a single problem untill i created the method close().

apprently when a client closes his connection with the database the BufferReader still wants input and throws an execption saying that `Java.net.socketExecption`: socket closed

since i have alot of different classes i will only post the ones that are failing at the moment if you need additional information please do not hesitate to send me a comment. Also since i am trying to learn from this project please comment on my code aswell if you feel like it :)

**Code (all of my code)**

```
public class ServerConnectionManager {

    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static Socket connection;
    private static ServerInformation ai = new ServerInformation();
    private static boolean connected = false;
    private static final int portNumber = 7070;
    private static int backLog = 100;

    /**
     * This method launches the server (and the application)!
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        startServer();
        waitForConnection();
    }


    /**
     *This method sets the serverSocket to portNumber and also adds the backLog.
     */
    private static void startServer() {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(portNumber, backLog);
            connected = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /**
     * This method waits for a connection aslong as the serverSocket is connected.
     * When a new client connects it creates an Object of the connection and starts the individual procedure.
     */
    private static void waitForConnection() {
        while (connected) {
            try {
                connection = server.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Connection c = new Connection(connection);
            ai.addToConnectionList(c);
            waitForConnection();
        }

    }


    public void closeMe(Socket con) {
        for (Connection conn : ai.getConnectionList()) {
            if (conn.getConnection() == con) {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
    }



}
```

**Connection**

```
public class Connection{
    private Socket connection;

    public Connection(Socket connection){
        this.connection = connection;
        ServerListner cl = new ServerListner(Connection.this);
        cl.start();
    }
    public Socket getConnection(){
        return this.connection;
    }
    public void close() {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

**ServerListner**

```
public class ServerListner extends Thread {

    private Socket connection;
    private BufferedReader br;
    private ChatPerson person;
    private Connection con;
    private ServerInformation ai = new ServerInformation();
    private ServerConnectionManager scm = new ServerConnectionManager();
    private ServerSender sender = new ServerSender();

    public ServerListner(Connection con){
        this.con = con;
        connection = con.getConnection();
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public Socket getConnection(){
        return this.connection;
    }
    public void run(){

        while (con.getConnection().isConnected()) {
            String inString;
            try {
                while ((inString = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    processInput(inString);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void processInput(String input){
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Connect")) {
            sender.sendMessageToConnection(this.connection, "Accepted");
        }
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("UserInformation")) {
            try {
                String username = br.readLine();
                person = new ChatPerson(username, connection);
                ai.add(person);
                System.out.println(ai.getList());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("SearchByCon")) {
            String name = ai.searchByConnection(connection);
            System.out.println(name);
        }
        if (input.equals("Disconnect")) {
            scm.closeMe(connection);
        }

    }
}
```

** Server Sender**

```
public class ServerSender {
    private PrintWriter pw;
    private ServerInformation ai = new ServerInformation();

    public void addToList(){

    }
    public void sendToAll(String message){
        for (Connection c : ai.getConnectionList()) {
            try {
                pw = new PrintWriter(c.getConnection().getOutputStream());
                pw.print(message);
                pw.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    /** 
     *
     * @param con
     * @param message
     */

    /*
     * Note - Denne metode gør også at jeg kan hviske til folk!:)
     */
    public void sendMessageToConnection(Socket con, String message){
        try {
            PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            print.println(message);
            print.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

** Server Information**

```
public class ServerInformation {
    private ArrayList<Connection> connectedClients = new ArrayList<Connection>();
    private ArrayList<ChatPerson> list = new ArrayList<ChatPerson>();


    public ArrayList<Connection> getConnectionList(){
        return connectedClients;
    }
    public void addToConnectionList(Connection con){
        connectedClients.add(con);
    }
    public String searchByConnection(Socket myConnection){
        for (ChatPerson p : list) {
            if (p.getConnection() == myConnection) {
                return p.getName();
            }

        }
        /*
         * If none found!
         */
        return null;
    }

    public void add(ChatPerson p){
        list.add(p);
    }

    public void removeByName(String name){
        for (ChatPerson p : list) {
            if (p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                list.remove(p);     
            }
        }
    }
    public String searchList(String name){
        for (ChatPerson p : list) {
            if (p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                return p.getName();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }   
    public ArrayList<ChatPerson>getList(){
        return list;
    }

}
```

** ChatPerson**

```
public class ChatPerson {
    private String chatName;
    private Socket connection;

    /*
     * This is for furture development
     * private Integer adminLevel;
     */

    public ChatPerson(String name, Socket connection){
        this.chatName = name;
        this.connection = connection;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.chatName = name;

    }
    public String getName(){
        return chatName;

    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Username: "+chatName;
    }
    public Socket getConnection(){
        return connection;
    }
}
```

I have tried the following thing(s):

```
try {
            String inString;
            while ((inString = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (inString.equalsIgnoreCase("Disconnect")) {
                    System.out.println(inString);
                    break;

                }else {
                    processInput(inString);
                }
            }
            scm.closeMe(connection);
```

This did not work still gave me the same execption.

Comment: in the SCM class you are not referencing you input argument con within the function closeMe. And where is ai.getConnectionList() fetching data from? You seem to be ignoring your input and referencing some class variable that hopefully references the same connection somewhere in the list but it would seem that your still missing. You might have gotten lucky but not this time.

Comment: im adding the rest of my classes so that it becomes more clear.

Comment: but why are you ignoring the input argument on the close me method? That makes unclear code at best.

Comment: @Bnjmn im not? the closeMe method gets a Socket as a parameter i search for that socket in my list and then close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (con.getConnection().isConnected()) {
            String inString;
            try {
                while ((inString = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    processInput(inString);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Having both these loops is meaningless. `readLine()` will return null as soon as EOS is reached, at which point you should close the socket and exit the loop. In any case `isConnected()` doesn't tell you anything about the state of the connection, only about which APIs you have called on your `Socket` which is the endpoint of it. Lose the outer loop.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close%28%2) says

> Any thread currently blocked in an I/O operation upon this socket will throw a SocketException.

You may want to break out of your readline() loop and close the connection outside of this.

Comment: if we look at the trace of that loop then it would go something like this (atleast in my mind) inString = "Disconnect" -> processInput("Disconnect")

if("Disconnect".equals("Disconnect"){
scm.closeMe(connection);
}

Conn.close()

Going back to the loop then the while(con.getConnection().isConnected()) would be false and it would no longer loop or am i wrong?

Comment: I know what While loop you ment now but how can i go around it?